# Download files based on input list Python

Tags: python, list, file, parsing, download

I'm trying to download files based on given list. My script does it well for me. However, I have one issue. It downloads just the first one. It doesn't iterate over the list. I've modified the code a little and now it's considering all the elements in the list to be one element and returns an error saying 'No such file or directory data\item1\nitem2\nitem3\nitem4\nitem5.txt' Here's a part of my code that parses the input list.

```
def get_data(name):
    file_name = os.path.join("data", name + ".txt")
    if not os.path.exists(file_name):
        sys.exit(-1)

    inF = open(file_name, "r") 
    lines = inF.readlines()
    data = ''.join(lines)

    return data
```

EDIT:

```
def download_final_data_for_data(data):
    url = "http://www.example.com/"+ data
    url_file = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_file)
    soup1 = str(soup)
    pattern=re.compile(r'''>final_data(.*?)</a>''')  
    data = pattern.findall(soup1)
    final_data_number = ''.join(data)
    return final_data_number

def get_data(name):
    data_list = []
    file_name = os.path.join("data", name + ".txt")
    if not os.path.exists(file_name):
        sys.exit(-1)

    inF = open(file_name, "r") 
    lines = inF.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data = line.strip()
        if len(data) > 1:
            data_list.append(data)
        else:
            data_list.append(sys.argv[1])
    return data_list
```

Comment: is "data" a string or a list?

Comment: You should probable iterate over the list of names outside of the function then just pass in the single name you want to process.

Comment: What `name` argument are you passing to `get_data()`? What does your input file look like? `readlines()` returns a list of lines in the file, but leaves the `\n` on the end of each of the items (strings).

Comment: @martineau Actually there is another script preceding it, where we give the list of names, for which it downloads the data. So for each name.txt will be its corresponding data. Now I need to give the same list of names, read those files from before (which is the data input here). It has multiple lines. My script should take one line at a time.

Comment: Your `data = ''.join(lines)` statement joins all the items `readlines()` returned into a single string (which includes the `\n` at the end of each of the items in the list). It's unclear why the error message contains "data\item1\nitem2\nitem3\nitem4\nitem5.txt" especially since you have an `os.path.exists()` call before trying to `open()` the file.

Comment: @martineau "data\item1\nitem2\nitem3\nitem4\nitem5.txt" is the file that its trying to write now. It is supposed to create files like "data\item1.txt" "data\item2.txt" and so on.

Comment: First of all, it trying to read a file, not write one. From what you're saying the value of the `name` argument that was passed to `get_data()` must have been `"\item1\nitem2\nitem3\nitem4\nitem5"` (note there's a missing "n" after the first "\"). Ignoring that deviation, it means you're passing the list a single string to the function rather than a Python 'list' container type. What value exactly do you want the function to return?

Comment: @martineau I defined 6 functions on the whole. 1. Does the actual download. 2. Gets the output path. 3. Saves the downloaded data. 4. Gets the list of names. 5. Gets the data for each name listed in previous function. 6. Runs everything in the required order. The function I showed above is number 5. I changed the function a little more (as shown in the edit above). Now it gives me the output only for the last item. Now I feel the issue's with function 1 actually (since it doesn't take all the data, where data is a 7-10 character alpha-numeric word), which I posted above too.

Comment: Can you please update your post to show all of the functions? Also include the command line that invokes your script (as `sys.argv` is also used in the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see where the problem is. The problematic part is:

```
file_name = os.path.join("data", name + ".txt")
```

in order to get the correct file-name you would have to iterate over the names somehow. In order to get a list of your names as you read them (and as they are present in the code right now) do a

```
namelist = name.split("/n") #this gives you a list that you can work on.
                            #alternatively read the file line-by-line (which you don't at the moment)
```

what your code does is joining the strings containing "data" , all the names you read with the newline characters and a ".txt" suffix. Anyway, then just do a

```
for name in namelist:
    #do stuff with name
    file_name = os.path.join("data",name+".txt")
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without seeing more context and a concrete example input, but it looks like `name` contains something like `item1\nitem2\nitem3\nitem4\nitem5`.  Have you printed it out to check?

I notice you're joining the `lines` together into one string, `data`.  If you did something like that with the parameter `name`, I'd expect to see something like what you're describing.

I'm guessing what you probably want to do is something like:

```
for fn in name:
    get_data(fn.strip())  # strip off possible trailing \n
```

but without joining `name` first.  If `name` is already a string like you've described, then you'd need to do something like this:

```
name = name.split('\n')
for fn in name:
    get_data(fn)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for name in namelist.split('\\'):
    data = get_data(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're passing a string into get_data() since you'd get a concatenation error otherwise. If that's the case, since the file name you get in your error includes line breaks and you're joining everything at the end of the method, I'm guessing you're joining the entirety of the input from a file. I can't, however, determine that without seeing what 'name' is.

If that's what you're doing, I'd suggest using *file*.readlines() and passing that into get_data. It would look something like:

```
for name in file.readlines():
    data = get_data(name)
```

Otherwise, if you need to read it all into one string for some reason, you might try:

```
names = name.split('\n')
for name in names:
    data = get_data(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your statements are not very clear I'll try to show a skeleton of my way of solving such task.

You can use argparse to tell the program to use certain files as the link-lists.

Argparse provides in the script below a CLI interface which you can call like this.

`python ./script.py -i list.txt -o ./`

To download everything to the currenty directoy (note this is not implemented)
Or use a bunch of files via
`python ./script.py -i lists/* -o ./`

```
import argparse   

def parseList(file):   # Parse the file, remove newlines/empty lines

    with open(file, 'r') as f: 
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
    return lines


def downloadLinks(links, output): # DOWNLOAD ALL THE LINKS!
    for link in links:
        print("Download me: %s" % link)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser('File Downloader')

    ap.add_argument('-i','--input',nargs='+', required=True, help='Path to the download list')
    ap.add_argument('-o','--output',required=True, help='Path to the output directory')

    args = vars(ap.parse_args())



    for file in args['input']:  # loop over all input files and process them
        parsedList = parseList(file)
        downloadLinks(parsedList, args['output'])
```